# How to make a join on Java with criteria builder

Tags: java, eclipse, join, spring-boot

I have a database in which I need to make a Join from Java with a CriteriaBuilder.

I have this code so far:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entman.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Company> query = cb.createQuery(Company.class);
    Root<Employee> teacher = query.from(Employee.class);
    Join<Employee, Company> employees = teacher.join("id");
    query.select(employees).where(cb.equal(teacher.get("name"), ""));

    List<Company> results = entman.createQuery(query).getResultList();

    return results;
```

After I run this code ( with springboot) i get this error: **Cannot join to attribute of basic type**

Does anyone know what should I do to make it work ?

PS: I will provide any other information if needed.
Thanks in advance.
[company database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hgKt.png)
[employee database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGvRG.png)

L.E.:
Employee:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Size(min = 1)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date hire_date;

    @ManyToOne
    //@JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Company company;

    public Employee() {}

    public Employee(Long id, String name, Date date, Company company) {
        setId(id);
        setName(name);
        setHire_date(date);
        setCompany(company);
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getHire_date() {
        return hire_date;
    }

    public void setHire_date(Date hire_date) {
        this.hire_date = hire_date;
    }

    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }
}
```

Company:

```
@Entity
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Size(min = 1)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval=true)
    private Collection<Employee> employees;

    public Company() {}

    public Company(Long id, String name) {
        setId(id);
        setName(name);
    }

    public Company(Long id, String name, Collection<Employee> employees) {
        setId(id);
        setName(name);
        setEmployees(employees);
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Collection<Employee> getEmployees() 
    {
        return employees;
    }

    public void setEmployees(Collection<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Company [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", employees=" + employees.toString() + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: I have answered similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38251392/hibernate-criteria-api-on-child-table/38251832#38251832

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Thank you for your response, I've read that, but it didn't help me understand where I was wrong...

Comment: Yeah the colleague bellow is correct. You can not join by a @Basic column mapping. You need to join on the relationship. You need to join on the Teacher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a `Teacher` element, not a reference to `id` because you cannot join a `@Column` field...

Change id mapping from `@Column`:

```
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
```

with a `@ManyToOne` (or the needed one) association:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private Teacher teacher;
```

After this your `join` will work as expected.

Comment: I added these annotations correctly ( i think ) but it seems that I have a slightly new error... Repeated column in mapping for entity: entity.Employee column: id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Comment: I should see your entities, but if you have it remove the mapping of the `Employee.id` in the `Company` entity, just map the `Employee`... if no, please share `Employee` and `Company` classes and mappings

Comment: The company entity:

Comment: @R3muSGFX please edit your question (and when possible, post code, not images!)

Comment: I added the code. The screenshots are from the database.

Comment: why is commented `//@JoinColumn(name = "id")`?? it seems exactly what you're missing

Comment: I made some modifications in the meantime and I've commented that line to stop showing me the error.